# Linux как заархивировать папку

Tags: linux, zip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу заархивировать всю папку www
как это сделать?

Comment: Опцию `-r` добавьте

Comment: Традиционно в *nix используют [tar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html). В вашем случае -- `tar czf www.tgz ./www`

Answer (score 2):

Для архивации целой папки необходимо использовать параметр `–r`, который инициирует рекурсивное архивирование. Без этого параметра будет заархивирована только папка без вложенных в неё файлов. Пример : `zip –r archive.zip dirname` или в Вашем случае  `zip -r www.zip www`. Просмотреть полный список возможностей архиватора zip  можно при помощи : `zip --help` или `man zip`. Если вы не хотите видеть вывод из zip при создании ZIP-файла, используйте параметр `-q`.